# PHP MySqli query not working but with no errors inside script tags

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I currently have a system whereby a list of users is generated with a mysqli query and for each user, a select option is echoed:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` > 0");
echo '<html><select id="contacts" onchange="announce(this.value)"><option value="Contact list">Contact List</option>';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<option value = '.$row['user_name'].'>'.$row['user_name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

What I need to happen is that a value be selected where `user` is equal to the user selected with this select box.  So, that is why there is this JavaScript:

```
function announce(user_name){
document.getElementById("Divvy").innerHTML="<?php 
$user='"+user_name+"';
if($user != 'Contact list'){
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `is_doing` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_name` = '{$user}'");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$doing = print_r($row);
}
echo $user.' is '.$doing;
}
?>";
}
```

All the PHP works other than the database query, about which I am confused, because:
1) Nothing is returned to $doing
2) The query is (I'm pretty sure) correct
3) No errors are shown with DIE(mysql_error());

I would appreciate some help on how to get this to work.

Comment: The syntax of JS is not correct which is pretty clear !!

Comment: n00b question, how would I amend it?

Comment: php with js ? ? server side with client side? i cant look to code like this.

Comment: I wasn't very keen on it but I don't know about any alternative (the only thing I could find about setting a php variable value equal to selected value was where the select box options were not dynamic)

Comment: You can't use Javascript variables in PHP like that. PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the client. PHP sends the entire page to the client and then it's done. To send JS variables to PHP, you have to submit a form or use AJAX. You need to go back and learn how the web works, you're totally confused.

Comment: I know that, but found this: http://ibence.com/new.php

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the error - you are not escaping the javascript strin (using double quote sign for quote: " before the SELECT statement and after the query is finished).

Replace

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `is_doing` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_name` = '{$user}'");
```

With
a

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, \"SELECT `is_doing` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_name` = '{$user}'\");
```

Comment: Thank you, but now all I see on the page is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) (on the line that you told me to amend).  Do you know what that could be?

Comment: Are you executing the JS function within a PHP file or it is a HTML / JS file?

Comment: it is within the .php file

Comment: Aha... OK. Disregard the prev. comment. It is valid if that is a HTML / JS file. The part  
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ $doing = print_r($row); } echo $user.' is '.$doing;
  seems irrelevant written that way. Rework it without the print_r

Comment: Do you believe that to be the problem part?